# How to check if value exists in another dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe below that contains mapping between french to english

```
df1 

french english
ksjks  an
sjk    def
ssad   sdsd
```

And another dataframe columns are in french so need to convert them into english by using df1

```
df2

ksjks sjk ssad
2     4    6
```

how can we achieve that?

```
new_cols = []
for col in df2.columns:
    if col in df1['french']:
             how to get corresponding english value
```

PS: Have just put random data in for sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Option 1***
Use `map` with `set_index`

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(df1.set_index('french').english)
print(df2)
```

***Option 2***
Use `rename` with `set_index`:

```
df2.rename(columns=df1.set_index('french').english.to_dict())
```

Both produce:

```
   an  def  sdsd
0   2    4     6
```

Order of the columns doesn't matter:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'french': ['un', 'deux', 'trois'], 'english': ['one', 'two', 'three']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]], columns=['trois', 'deux', 'un'])

df2.rename(columns=df1.set_index('french').english.to_dict())

   three  two  one
0      1    2    3

df2.columns.map(df1.set_index('french').english)
# Index(['three', 'two', 'one'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: it says :TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
plus it is not necessary that order of french values are in same order as columns of other dataframe

Comment: it is not necessary that order of french values are in same order as columns of other dataframe

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_lookup= pd.DataFrame({"French":["ksjks","sjk","ssad"],"english": 
["an","def","sdsd"]})

df_actual=pd.DataFrame({"ksjks":[2],"sjk":[4],"ssad":[6]})

df_actual.columns=[ df_lookup.loc[df_lookup.loc[df_lookup["French"]== 
col].index[0],"english"] for col in df_actual.columns]
```